# Ng-Model not updating in controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using [ion-datetime-picker](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker) and it is working in that I have the popup appear and can select a date and time which then shows in the HTML DOM, but I have a ng-model attached to the popup, but when I try to access the variable in the controller it does not get updated. I have made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/spennyf/pen/LkoXdE) to demonstrate the functionality of what I am seeing, why does the variable not get updated in the `$rootScope`?

Here is code:
HTML

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h2 class="title">ion-datetime-picker demo</h2>
        <button ng-click="getDate()">Get Date</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
            <div class="item item-icon-left" ion-datetime-picker monday-first ng-model="datetimeValue">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-browsers-outline positive"></i>
                Monday as the first day:
                <strong>{{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm"}}</strong>
            </div>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
angular.module("demo", ["ionic", "ion-datetime-picker"])
.run(function($rootScope){

$rootScope.datetimeValue = new Date();
$rootScope.getDate = function() {
    alert($rootScope.datetimeValue);
}


};
});
```

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

currently I have this as my HTML

```
<div class="" ion-datetime-picker monday-first only-valid="{'after': 'today', 'inclusive': true}" ng-model="datetimeValue">
                    <h3><b>Date Required By</b></h3>
                    <p id="datetimeP">{{datetimeValue| date: "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm"}}<p>
                </div>
```

And then in my controller I have

```
 console.log("datetime: " + $scope.datetimeValue);
```

And datetime is undefined, but I see it in the HTML

Comment: Need to see your code

Comment: @DevlshOne added code

Comment: You should be using a small `modal` rather than a new window.

Comment: @DevlshOne could elaborate please

Comment: http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/